# [Tikz-]Qtree: force direction of single child to left or right?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees, trees, tikz-qtree

I'm trying to draw a tree that has internal nodes with only one child, but which must be oriented.

```
    /
    \
    /\
      \
      /\
```

Instead of the typical qtree where said children just "hang":

```
    |
    |
   / \
      |
      |
     / \
```

I think (but I do not know how) it might be possible to have invisible leaves to force the direction, but perhaps (hopefully) there is a better solution? This can be in either qtree or tikz-qtree...

**EDIT**: follow-up question that would be useful, how can make each branch (in a straight line) distinct when the nodes are not labeled -- i.e., when the tree is has several connections in a row, like in the second example, how can I make them slightly spaced from one another so they do not form a straight undistinguishable line?

**EDIT 2**: thanks your response, I now have these two trees:

```
  \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz-qtree}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}\footnotesize
    \Tree [ \edge node[midway,left] {000};
          [ \edge[draw=none]; {} \edge node[midway,right] {111};
            [
            \edge node[midway,left] {0}; $U_2$
            \edge node[midway,right] {11};
            [ \edge[draw=none]; {} \edge node[midway,right] {11};
            [ \edge node[midway,left] {0}; $U_1$
                \edge node[midway,right] {1}; $U_3$ ] ] ] ]
          \edge[draw=none]; {}  ]
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}\footnotesize
    \Tree [ \edge node[midway,right] {$U_1=U_2$, $U_1=U_3$};
          [.. \edge node[midway,right] {$U_1=U_2$, $U_1=U_3$};
          [ \edge node[midway,left] {$0$}; $U_2$ 
              \edge node[midway,right] {$U_1\not=U_2$, $U_1 = U_3$}; [
                  \edge node[midway, right] {$U_1 = U_3$}; 
                  [ \edge node[midway, left] {$0$}; $U_1$
                      \edge node[midway, right] {$U_1\not=U_3$}; $U_3$ ] ] ] ] ]
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Any idea on how to make them look better?

Answer (score 5):

Use an empty node `{}` and place an `\edge[draw=none];` in front of it.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{
    n/.style={draw=none},
    every node/.append style={inner ysep=+0pt,outer ysep=+0pt,minimum size=+0pt}
}
\begin{document}
\Tree
    [.{}
        [.{} 
            \edge[n];[.{} ]
            [.{}
                {} 
                [.{}
                    \edge[n];[.{} ]
                    [.{} 
                        {} 
                        {} 
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        \edge[n];{} 
    ]
\end{document}
```

### Output (without and with `every node` style activated)

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Thank you. But such a tree looks a bit disjointed?

Comment: @Jérémie Well, if you really do not write anything in the nodes, then yes, they won’t connect, but this can be forced with the given `every node` style. (See updated answer.)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `xshift` (and `yshift`) to fine-tune where you want your nodes to be.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}\footnotesize
  \Tree [.{a}
      \edge node[midway,left] {1};
      [.\node[xshift=0.5cm,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt] {}; \edge node[midway,left] {2}; {c} ]
  ]
\end{tikzpicture}
```